# Moshi-JsonDataException: Required value '%s' missing at $

Tags: android, json, moshi

I was working with Moshi to pull JSON data from an API and map it to my DTO Data classes when I encountered this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.plcoding.weatherapp, PID: 9706
> com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Required value 'weatherData'
> missing at $ at
> com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.missingProperty(Util.java:649) at
> com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapter.fromJson(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:103)
> at
> com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:41)

My DTO are annotated with `@field:Json(name = "xyz")`

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class WeatherDataDTO(

    @field:Json(name = "time")
    val times: List<String>,
    @field:Json(name = "temperature_2m")
    val temperatures: List<Double>)
```

I have enclosed the above DTO in another DTO.

```
JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class WeatherDTO(

    @field:Json(name = "hourly")
    val weatherData: WeatherDataDTO

)
```

I am using the latest `Retrofit` and `Moshi` Libs on `Kotlin 1.6.10`

```
// Retrofit, Core Moshi JSON Library and Moshi's Kotlin support and converter factory
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.12.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.12.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
```

My Json endpoint looks this:

```
{
"latitude": 42,
"longitude": 36,
"generationtime_ms": 0.3489255905151367,
"hourly": {
"time": [],
"temperature_2m": []
.....
}
```

Have struggled with this error for days but cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing  `@field:Json()` in favor of just `@Json(name = "xyz")` did the trick for me.

My DTO now looks like this and is working fine!

```
 @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class WeatherDataDTO(
    
        @Json(name = "time")
        val times: List<String>,
        @Json(name = "temperature_2m")
        val temperatures: List<Double>)
```

**Edit**

Also, check the error for the *required value*.

For instance, the Json name was  **`@Json(name = "name")`** but I had accidentally renamed it to  **`@Json(name = "cityName")`**.

This also causes the same exception.

For more info on `@field:Json(name = "xyz")` vs `@Json(name = "xyz")` you can review this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56976656/moshi-in-kotlin-json-vs-fieldjson).

I also found [this article](https://androidexample365.com/automatically-filled-the-declared-non-null-field-is-missing-or-null-with-default-value/) to be helpful in case the ***Moshi-JSON Exception*** persists.

Happy Coding ...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was migrating from gson to moshi and first I got the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Cannot serialize Kotlin type com.xxx.Spot. Reflective serialization of Kotlin classes without using kotlin-reflect has undefined and unexpected behavior. Please use KotlinJsonAdapter from the moshi-kotlin artifact or use code gen from the moshi-kotlin-codegen artifact.

Then I resolved it with adding `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` on data class like your WeatherDataDTO that you did and right after that came the exception you mentioned in this post.

I have done what you posted in your answer, added the `@Json(name)` but because my data class fields that was getting the errors were null, I was getting that same error.

In my data class I had somewhat like this:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class WeatherDataDTO(
    
        @Json(name = "time")
        val times: List<OtherDataClass>
    )
```

And the OtherDataClass:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class OtherDataClass(
        @Json(name = "time")
        val problematicString: String, //This was causing the problem if it was null
            //and the String was non-nullable(without a "?" questionmark beside of String)
    )
```

What I did in OtherDataClass was making problematicString nullable:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class OtherDataClass(
        @Json(name = "problemString")
        val problematicString: String? = null, // Made it nullable and initialized it as a null.
        //...other variables...
    )
```

Also I got the information from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660364/moshi-1-9-1-cannot-serialize-kotlin-type)

I hope this helps someone with the same exception.